# How to add Facebook page feed posts and comments in Universal Windows Platform c#

Tags: c#, windows, facebook, facebook-graph-api, uwp

How to add Facebook page feed posts and comments in Universal Windows Platform c#

I want to add my facebook page's posts and comments and how many likes in posts 
but I didn't find any help ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the UWP Community toolkit Facebook Service class , I have written sample application , How to get Facebook post into the UWP application.
URL as given below.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/facebook-service-into-uwp-app-using-uwp-community-toolkit/

Hope it will useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possible way that you can embed comments with webview control

Reference :https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-comments#desktoplayout

XAML Code:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <WebView x:Name="MyWebView"/>
</Grid>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void LoadLocalHtml()
    {
        MyWebView.Navigate(new Uri("ms-appx-web:///Assets/demo.html"));
    }
}
```

demo.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>DEMO</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bmap.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
        (function (d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.6";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

    <div class="fb-comment-embed"
         data-href="https://www.facebook.com/zuck/posts/10102735452532991?comment_id=1070233703036185"
         data-width="500"></div>
    <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/comment_embed.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fzuck%2Fposts%2F10102577175875681%3Fcomment_id%3D1193531464007751%26reply_comment_id%3D654912701278942&width=320&include_parent=true&height=332&appId" width="320" height="332" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```